# Encontrar palavras compostas em uma expressão

Tags: python, regex

A duvida consiste em encontrar como identificar palavras compostas em uma expressão com regex

Exemplo:

```
teste de status:cancelada and teste de numero:15418782218
```

Objetivo:

Ter encontrado **teste de status** e **teste de numero**

Estava utilizando até então a seguinte expressão regex antes de sugir a necessidade de ter palavras compostas:

Python:

```
query = "status:cancelada and numero:15418782218"
regex = "\w{1,}(?=:)"
match = re.findall(regex, query)
```

Como o objeto final é montar uma sintaxe lucene, creio que um coringa seria seus operadores booleanos:

```
"AND", "+", "OR", "NOT","-"
```

Todavia não encontrei uma forma de utiliza-los.

Preciso desses campos pois client da API recebe a expressão da forma descrita acima porque o client não conhece os campos especificos que tenho na base, apenas tem uma ideia, logo atraves desses campos conseguiria fazer um de-para para os campos corretos.

Considerando a expressão acima.
Exemplo:

de:

```
teste de status:cancelada and teste de numero:15418782218
```

para:

```
campo_status_:cancelada and campo_numero:15418782218
```

com isso conseguiria realizar a consulta.

Comment: Se o and, or, etc são palavras chaves como separadores, então **não** precisa de [tag:regex], bastaria dividir a string baseado nessas palavras chaves, claro que existe a questão do escape em sintaxe lucene, o que vai exigir bem mais do que dividir ou que regex, na verdade em situações quem envolvem possíveis escapes penso que usar regex poderá ter dificuldades ou situações que serão impossíveis de resolver a string. Sendo Python talvez seja melhor usar algo pronto, como: https://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/index.html

Comment: Acontece que expressão não vem pronta, preciso dos campos para poder fazer um "de-para" com outros campos para então montar a expressão correta

Comment: Não tenho certeza, talvez seja o caso de começar a estudar *análise léxica*, se deseja criar a própria sintaxe, semelhante ao lucene.

Comment: A conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142108/discussion-on-question-by-victor-henrique-encontrar-palavras-compostas-em-uma-ex)